# How To Intercept @RequestBody Binding

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using the latest version of Spring Boot, I'm developing a REST API. I'm sending JSON into the request and the automatic binding using `@RequestBody` of the JSON to the Entity is usually good enough, but there are times when I want to intercept this binding and manipulate it slightly. I'm unsure on how to hook into that process, if it is possible.

I know that I could use a DTO and then do whatever, but I'm looking to do something a bit more global instead of case by case in each controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a HandleInterceptor to intercept the request before it's actually processed by your controller method in the **preHandle** method of the interceptor and manipulate it in any way you want. It will be global for all of your controllers although I believe you can further customise it for specific ones. Have a look [here](http://spring-java4dev.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) for an example how to do it. Basically you only need to override a method from the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.